# Getting Re-Motivated for a Side Project I Am Doing Alone

Tags: project-management

I started converting one of Asp.Net Webforms projects into MVC.  When I first started on it, I was really into it, working 1-2 hours on it every night.  I got a ton of it done, but then something happened.

I divided the project up into small chunks using AgileZen to list tasks.  I am now to the point where I don't want to work on it.  I only have a few items left to do, some of them would be fun to do like making the paging work with AJAX, but I can't seem to get there.  Every time I start working on the project, I last about 3 minutes, then move on to something else.

Anyone have any suggestions for how to get re-motivated, or what I can do to keep me from working for a few minutes then running away.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean and I am doing what Jonathan suggests.  Take time off.  Do other things. I am even doing some other coding things but nothing I feel obligated to do, just fun.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, sometimes you have to reassess a project.  It may not be worth doing anymore or you may rediscover why you wanted to do it in the first place.  Start with pros and cons and ask yourself if you sould finish this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a big project I've been working on for the past couple years. At times I really don't want to get back into it, so then I start other mini projects. Take a few days, weeks, or even months off. Then it feels fresh and new when I get back into it.

Comment: But then you end up with 10 uninished side projects instead of 1...

Comment: Who says you don't finish the other projects? They are mini after all. Or just start a project where you just want to try out a new technology and it doesn't matter if you finish or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take a short vacation. Go out to dinner and a movie - get away for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Make it open-source and post the link here. Or at least imagine you are going to and get the project finished in such a way that you would not be shamed to put it out into the open.